# Validate dynamic checkboxes Django form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have form in Django which is generating names of people in checkbox according to chosen group of people (for sending message)

```
class MessageForm(forms.Form):

    people = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=1000, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'style': 'width: 100%; height: 150px;'}))

    def __init__(self, people_list, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['people'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=people_list)
```

When I put it in template view as

```
return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': MessageForm(people)})
```

It renders chosen people in the form. But my problem is how to validate that form because

```
form = MessageForm(request.POST, people_list=people)
```

or

```
form = MessageForm(people_list=people, request.POST)
```

makes error about when I want to validate that form like

```
if form.is_valid():
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form = MessageForm(people, data=request.POST)` would do it.

But you shouldn't change the form init's signature. You should make `people_list` a kwarg so that you preserve `request` as the first positional arg:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    people_list = kwargs.pop('people_list', None)
    super(MessageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```